# Calculate jQuery text().length of Visible elements without removing hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clone

I think this is a small problem but I am stuck, somehow.

Consider the following code

HTML:

```
<div class="india">
   <p class="hidden"> Uttar Pradesh </p>
   <p> Andhra Pradesh </p>
   <p class="hidden"> Uttar Pradesh </p>
   <p> Andhra Pradesh </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
   display: none;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
/* Case 1: No of char inside div when hidden elements are removed
RETURNS 53 */
$('div.india').find(":hidden").remove();
alert($('div.india').text().length);
```

**Now I want to return the same length (=53) without removing the hidden elements. I have tried doing the following things (one by one/ or on a separate similar div), but they all return different length**

How can I return the same length without removing hidden elements? Explanations why they are different length are welcomed!

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/deveshz/R2QNM/1/

```
// Without Removing hidden div RETURNS 32
/*Case 2: */
alert($('div.india').find(":visible").text().length);

/* Case 3 */
var charlength = 0;
$('div.india').find(":visible").each(function(){
    charlength += $(this).text().length;
});
alert(charlength);

/*Case 4 RETURNS 21*/ 
var clone = $('div.india').clone();
clone.find(":hidden").remove();
alert(clone.text().length);
```

Comment: looks like the first length call includes spaces and possibly carriage returns.  The 'alert($('div.india').find(":visible").text().length);' doesnt.  Try alerting the actuall text before the length alerts and you will see the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the inputs of @kasper and @Richard

I tried doing this:

> alert($('div.india').text().length -
>   $('div.india').find(":hidden").text().length);

and got the correct answer. Thank you for your help.

**Now this will be a great question if we can find out why clone is returning 21**

Comment: @kasper: Let me know if there is any other way rather than subtraction.

Answer (score 2):

this

```
$('div.india').find(":hidden").remove();
alert($('div.india p').text());
alert($('div.india p').text().length);
```

seems to give the same result as

```
alert($('div.india').find(":visible").text().length);
alert($('div.india').find(":visible").text());
```

when i tested it

Comment: Yeah as @kasperTaeymans mentioned. But my problem is how can I get the length of 53 without removing div. I have already understood that CASE 2 returns the length of visible p inside div.india rather than div itself. Please help

Answer (score 1):

case one and two are different because... (see comments in code)

```
    //Case 1: No of char inside div when hidden elements are removed
    RETURNS 53 */
    $('div.india').find(":hidden").remove();
    alert($('div.india').text().length);//here your selector is a div
    alert($('div.india p').text().length);//here it is a p tag... ->32



    // Without Removing hidden div RETURNS 32
    /*Case 2: */
    alert($('div.newindia').find(":visible").text().length);//here your selector points to a visible p tag
```

I'm thinking about the clone case...  :-/

edit:removed part of my answer because i did something wrong in jsfiddle

Comment: But how can I get the count of div. I mean the value of 53 rather than 32 without removing. I understood the reason for CASE 2 though!

Comment: If that is the case why does 

alert($('div.india').text().length - $('div.india').find(":hidden").text().length);

returns 53, even then I am not removing anything from here? See my answer below

Comment: No worries. Could you find why the clone method is behaving like that?

Answer (score 1):

I found why the clone method gives an other result...

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/R2QNM/3/

you can't use :visible or :hidden on a clone element if it is not in the dom. However you could check if they have a particular class or not.

```
$('div.india').find(":hidden").remove();
alert('not clone '+$('div.india').text().length);


var clone = $('div.newindia').clone();

alert('clone '+ clone.find("p:not(.hidden)").text().length);
```